# How to deal with "QXcbConnection" error message when running a python script in a local machine on a remote desktop if plotting is part of the output?

Tags: python-3.x, ssh, qt5, cat, xcb

I am trying to run a python script written in my local machine on a remote desktop using the following command line on terminal:

```
cat myscript.py | ssh username@machinename.departmentname.universityname.edu python
```

Python 3 under Anacanoda3 is installed on both local and remote machines. Here is the error message in the middle of the run while trying to display the plot:

> QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display

What could be the reason and how to fix it? There were some other posts related to the same error message but for different reasons/usages.

Comment: try with `cat myscript.py | ssh -X username@machinename.departmentname.universityname.edu python`

Comment: That works except that it tries to locate the script in the remote machine rather than looking for it in the local machine. In other words, my script is in my current local machine and I just want to run it on the remote desktop.

Comment: try with: `cat myscript.py | ssh "DISPLAY=:0" username@machinename.departmentname.universityname.edu python`

Comment: I am getting: "ssh: Could not resolve hostname display=:0: Name or service not known"

Comment: I had x11vnc installed. I think it was interfering with the code. I removed it and now trying both of your recommendations again. Still not working.

Comment: I understand that the script is on your pc, if so the first command should work.

Comment: The first command still takes a different script with the same name on the remote machine and from the output I know that it is not the same script on the local machine.

Comment: Do you have 2 scripts with the same name on both machines?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147870/discussion-between-allan-and-eyllanesc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use the -X parameter to activate window sharing.

```
cat myscript.py | ssh -X username@machinename.departmentname.universityname.edu python
```

Comment: This is interesting. You are right. The first command does work. However what is weird about the command line suggested is that it is not taking care of the auxiliary python codes inside the main code. In other words. When the code reaches the line "import settings". It thinks that it has to look for the file "settings.py" in the remote machine which is again present in the local machine withe the same name. This file initializes values and it is apparent that running your command takes the values inside the version that is in the remote machine.

Comment: Is there a way to direct the command to look for the imports inside the local machine instead other than renaming "settings.py" modules?

Comment: It is that cat copies the contents of the file, it does not execute it. That text for example will say import mymodule, and the remote python will look in the remote folders, python does not know that the package is elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.